# SpringToolSuite is unable to recognize spring boot annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

I got a project from GitHub which is a Java spring boot application running with Maven dependencies.
I am so confused why I can't run the application successfully on STS.
There's no longer a problem on my old laptop. Because I just changed my laptop, this problem only occurred on this laptop.

The details / symptoms of the issue are:

- When I typed "SpringToolSuite" on my start panel, no applications were being recognized. So I have to open STS manually from Downloads (ie. its original file location). But anyways, it is just a minor issue.
- In STS, annotations such as the lombok log and most of the getter/setter methods were unrecognized.
- Failed to perform "Run as Spring Boot App" from STS, but it is successful when I tried to perform "mvn clean install" to create a Maven build from command prompt.
- Error message: "log cannot be resolved"

I tried finding results from other posts here but to no avail.

The steps that I import the project is:

1. Create another folder as the workspace.
2. Open STS by selecting the created folder as the workspace.
3. Click File > Import and import as existing Maven project (as it is a Maven-built application).

I also tried to create a Maven build from command prompt, which is successful eventually.

As the situation was so strange here, please advise further what I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok has a plugin for Eclipse (and therefore STS as well) that enhances the IDE with direct support for Lombok: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Without that extension the IDE is not really able to recognize and support Lombok.

Comment: Thanks so much for this info. I've successfully configured my IDE!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your suggestions.

First of all, I've made sure my STS the latest version. I installed it from the official site https://spring.io/tools.
[I downloaded the Windows one. See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtUHS.png)
I executed the spring-tool-suite-4-4.16.1.RELEASE-e4.25.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar file afterwards. A folder with STS application inside has been generated.

Referring to your second question, I am sure I have the lombok dependency.
[This is part of my pom.xml. See image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkayY.png)
I also performed again the "mvn clean install". It is success and error-free.

Fyi, I also make sure every setup is right, such as:

- It is pointing to the same java version as what Maven points to.
- In STS, the Java compliance level is the same as the java version I defined in PATH environment variable.
- Also in STS, the Installed JRE is pointing to the right folder.

But as the STS is still not recognizing Spring Boot annotations. That's why it seems weird here. For example, logs are underlined red with an error message on the IDE. Getters and Setters of @Data fields are not implicitly referenced with that spring boot annotation since they're also underlined with error.